# Does anyone know any good sources/books regarding ancient Armenian mythology?

Tags: comparative, source-request, pantheon

I have been trying to find sources online about Armenian mythology but since the culture is so old and the Church burned so many texts about their paganism, I have difficulty finding anything. Most sources online differ from each other and the very few books that I have found are wildly inaccurate, short and unhelpful. I think it's about time someone brought Armenian mythology into the light and gave it the same amount of love as Greek mythology so if anyone can give me anything, I'd be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 3):

There are two that you can download from Project Gutenberg for free.

- [Armenian Legends And Poems by Z. C. Boyajian (2017)](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/54036)
- [Armenian Legends And Festivals by L. A. Boettiger (2011)](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/38129)

Comment: @Yannis, thanks for tidying that up.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely check these out!!